# Regular expression, that will be cut fragment of the cyrillic text with cyrillic keyword(case insensitive) and bold it

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have cyrillic text and some keyword(or part of it). I need to show 5 words before keyword, then full keyword in bold tag, and then 5 words. For example:

Full text: "Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Вдали от всех живут они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика большого языкового океана. Маленький ручеек Даль журчит по всей стране и обеспечивает ее всеми необходимыми правилами."

Keyword is "АНТИК" **(that's why case insensitive)**.

Result, that i need: "...в буквенных домах на берегу **Семантика** большого языкового океана. Маленький ручеек..."

Comment: Did you try something we could see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$word = "АНТИК";

$pattern = '~^.*?((?>\w++\W++){0,5})(\w*'.$word.'\w*+)((?>\W++\w++){0,5}).*$~usi';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, '$1<strong>$2</strong>$3', $text);
```

The fact that your text is written with cyrillic characters don't matter if you use the \w character class (that match every letters digit and underscore). Note that you can replace `\w` by `\pL` or `\p{Cyrillic}`. as you want.

Comment: Thanks! It works exactly as I need!!

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with:

```
$str = "Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Вдали от всех живут они в буквенных домах на берегу Семантика большого языкового океана. Маленький ручеек Даль журчит по всей стране и обеспечивает ее всеми необходимыми правилами.";
$kwd = "АНТИК";
preg_match("#((\p{Cyrillic}+ \.?){0,5}(\p{Cyrillic}*$kwd\p{Cyrillic}*)( \p{Cyrillic}+){0,5})#iu", $str, $m);
echo $m[1];
```